# wrap html5 canvas inside <body>

Tags: jquery, css, html, html5-canvas

I have a `canvas` which is initialised with `width:100%` but later the canvas width is increased .so the canvas's width is more than the `<body>` 's width and i want to wrap that canvas inside `<body>`. How can it be achieved?

I tried using Jquery `wrap` like `j$("body").wrap("<canvas>")` but it creates a new `canvas` and wraps  the body.

Please help!

Comment: if you don't want the canvas to go more than 100% of body then give `max-width:100%` css

Comment: @CerlinBoss i want it to have larger width.

Comment: set canvas `max-width:100%`

Comment: if the canvas width is more than body width then it **WILL** overflow. You can just hide it or add scroll

Answer (score 0):

Dimensions of elements which you are drawing in canvas should all be relative to canvas height/width.

For example, here canvas is always square and canvas line is diagonal.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('my-canvas');
canvas.height = canvas.width;

if (canvas.getContext) {
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.lineWidth = 10;

    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(0, 0);
    context.lineTo(canvas.height, canvas.width);
    context.stroke();
}
```

So no fixed dimensions.

And it can be easier if we know what you're drawing.